# AngularJS : Passing value from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Sorry for duplicating the question. But I found something useful and updated with it.

This is my directive :

```
App.directive('mapUsa', [function() {

return {

    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.vectorMap({
            map: 'us_aea_en',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            zoomButtons: false,
            regionStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: '#343434' 
                },
                hover: {
                    fill: '#242424'
                }
            },
            markerStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: '#F0A518',
                    stroke: '#F0A518',
                }
            },
            onRegionClick: function(event, code) {

            },
            markers: [
                {latLng: [37.78, -122.41], name: 'San Francisco', style: {r: 10}},
                {latLng: [40.71, -74], name: 'New York City', style: {r: 15}},
                {latLng: [41.89, -87.62], name: 'Chicago', style: {r: 5}},
                {latLng: [34.00, -118.25], name: 'Los Angeles', style: {r: 20}},
                {latLng: [34.00, -106.00], name: 'New Mexico', style: {r: 10}},
                {latLng: [44.50, -100.00], name: 'South Dakota', style: {r: 13}},
                {latLng: [25.78, -80.22], name: 'Miami', style: {r: 7}},
            ]
        });

    },
    controller: ['$scope', 'citiesData', function($scope, citiesData) {

        citiesData.getCitiesData()

        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.cities = data;

        }, function(errorStatus) {
            $scope.errorStatus = errorStatus;
        })



    }]

}

}])
```

In my controller I'm loading a json file and I can of course access it with my HTML using the angular expression.

But now on the `onRegionClick` I get the code of the cities whenever I click on a region.

And this is how JSON looks like.

```
{ "US-AL": { "name": "Alabama", "population": 4833722 }, "US-AK": { "name": "Alaska", "population": 735132 }
```

I have created JSON objects with code I get from the `onRegionClick`.

I wanted to print out the population count from the city code I get on `onRegionClick` and passing to it the controller and then finally using that code to get the data from JSON.

Please do help me out in this. As I didn't seriously couldn't understand on how to pass a param value from directive to a controller.

In my HTML I used expression like this from the variable created in the controller.

```
{{ cities.AL.name }}
```

It is ofc working fine. But I wanted to replace the `AL` with the code I get from the `onRegionClick`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried my answer on your other question? [answer on duplicate version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990807/angular-js-jvector-map-accessing-onregionclick/24990872#24990872)

Comment: Yes. It didn't work for me. Sorry for not replying on it.

Comment: Object can generally communicate with each other using events. Angular has emitter/listener methods available on the `scope` and `rootScope` which can be used. As in `$on`, `$emit`, `$brodcast`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/scope-emit-and-on-angularjs for difference between `$emit` and `$broadcast`

Comment: I tried this `onRegionClick: function(event, code) {scope.cityCode = code
console.log(scope.cityCode);},` Actually it does output the city code in the console whenever I click on the regions. But I'm unable to access the `cityCode` using the angular expression.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a filter? Maybe you can use the angular default filter and display the filtered data.

json:

```
{
   {
      "code": "US-AL",
      "name": "Alabama",
      "population": 4833722
   }, {
      "code": "US-AK",
      "name": "Alaska",
      "population": 735132
   }
}
```

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="city in cities | filter:inputCode">
   <td>{{city.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: My json doesn't look like it and I wanted to access the code param which I get on the `onRegionClick`.

Comment: How about $rootScope?

Comment: To add $rootScope in directive?